# What is the exact meaning of EPTP with Extended Page Tables?

Tags: virtual-machines, virtual-memory

**EPT** stands for Intel Extended Page Tables.
But what does the suffix P stand for in the term **EPTP switching** ?

If there is a reliable source, I would like to add the answer to the [Second Level Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Level_Address_Translation) Wikipedia article.

Comment: What is the context of this phrase? Where did you find it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I found it [here](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7619141/) and [here](https://secret.club/2020/04/13/how-anti-cheats-detect-system-emulation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel made it up. It stands for Extended Page Table Pointer, and it is a table which (as the name suggests) points into the extended page table. See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3C: System Programming Guide, Part 3](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3c-part-3-manual.pdf), section 24.6.11 for a full description of the EPTP and the EPT table to which it points.

Comment: That manual doesn't tell anything about switching the EPT or the EPT pointer. It sounds natural to switch the EPT by switching the pointer to it, but talking about switching the EPTP explicitly instead of switching the EPT (implicitly by changing the pointer to it) seems to impose a difference. So is there a difference between _EPT switching_ and _EPTP switching_ ?

Comment: @Juergen At this point you probably should be reading the kernel source or talking to the relevant developers. This was already far beyond the scope of this site.